# Why does getResourceAsStream with an empty string return an empty InputStream?

Tags: java

I just came across some peculiar behavior with getResourceAsInputStream that I was hoping someone could shed some light on.

Passing this method the name of a nonexistent resource returns null, like I'd expect. However, passing it an empty or space-filled string actually returns a valid InputStream with zero bytes in it. Only empty or space-filled strings seem to do this; whitespace like "\t" or "\n" will result in a null.

Is this intended behavior? If so, what is it's purpose?

```
this.class.getResourceAsStream("no_such_resource"); // returns null
this.class.getResourceAsStream("");                 // returns an InputStream
this.class.getResourceAsStream("    ");             // returns an InputStream
this.class.getResourceAsStream("\t");               // returns null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getResourceAsStream` asks the ClassLoader to construct a URL for the path. The path with an empty string or blanks at the end points to the directory of files where your classes .class file resides, so it constructs a `FileURLConnection` object. `getResourceAsStream` in turn asks that object to `getInpuStream()` and the implementation builds up a sorted directory listing in a string, converts it to bytes according to the default locale and gives you a `ByteArrayInputStream` on these bytes.

FileURLConnections behaviour is not very well documented, but if your search...

Comment: Great explanation! It's worth noting that this is a quirk of `FileURLConnection` which is not shared by `JarURLConnection`; running exactly the same code, but with the classes packed into a jar, will not produce a listing (according to my tests, at least).

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
InputStream is = this.class.getResourceAsStream("");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(line);
br.close();
```

this will print a list of classes that are located in the same directory of the current class. For example:

```
a.class
CallablePrintTask.class
java.policy.applet
RunnablePrintTask.class
ZoomableImageFrame.class
ZoomableImageFrame$FlagHolder.class
ZoomableImageFrame$ImageViewer.class
ZoomableImageFrame$LoadAction.class
ZoomableImageFrame$LoadAction$1.class
ZoomableImageFrame$ScaleAction.class
```

Comment: Good illustration of what's going on. I assume the reason I was getting an empty stream instead of results like this has something to do with testing my hypotheses in the Groovy console....

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the following:

```
this.class.getResourceAsStream("no_such_resource"); // returns null
this.class.getResourceAsStream("");                 // returns an InputStream
this.class.getResourceAsStream("    ");             // returns an InputStream
this.class.getResourceAsStream("\t");
```

`getResourceAsStream("c:\t")` <-- is valid.

It is coincidence that `\t` is a tab character.  Yet it is perfectly valid to have that as a path to look up.

Comment: I don't think so. To make a valid Java String of a backslash delimited path, you'd have to escape the backslashes. In other words, you'd have to do this `getResourceAsStream("c:\\t")`. It is not the same as a tab character at all.